# Como ter restrição e ao mesmo tanto permissão no CloudFire Store

Tags: firebase, firebase-database

Estou utilizando o firebase como banco de dados, especificamente o cloudFire store database. Tenho um campo chamado comentário, que quero que ao mesmo tempo seja lido por todos os usuários, mas somente o administrador possa apagá-lo. No entanto, quando adiciono a regra do delete, a read deixa de funcionar. Segue a estrutura que estou utilizando (editada para o tópico):

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /avaliacoes/{document=**} {

      allow read, create: if true;
    }
    match /block/{document=**} {

      allow read, update, delete, create: if request.auth.uid == 'uid_do_admin'; //parte editada para o topico
    }
    match /comentarios/{document=**} {

      allow create: if true;
      allow read: if true;
      allow update: if true;
      allow delete: if request.auth.uid == 'id_do_administrador'; // editado para o tópico
    }

    match /empresas/{document=**} {

      allow read, create: if true;
    }
    match /favoritos/{document=**} {

      allow read, create: if true;
    }
    match /users/{document=**} {

      allow read, create: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual o resultado do relatório de testes para essas regras?